# Dynamic data are not rendering on the browser

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Good day, I'm trying to create a MEARN stack application with react-redux. I am already able to post data to my MongoDB atlas, and I am also able to fetch the data and console.log it. But when I try to render the data to my front end the browser returns an empty page. I would like to know what is causing this issue. This is my first time creating a react application.

```
import './Experience.css';

import Post from './Posts/Post';

import { Grid, CircularProgress  } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function Experience() {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
  console.log(posts); //Logged my data on DevTool -> Console (see image below)
  return (
    !posts.length ? <CircularProgress /> : (
      <Grid container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
        Test //view browser
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <Grid key={post._id} item xs={3} >
            <Post post={post} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    )
  );
}

export default Experience;
```

[image]

```
import React from 'react';

 import { Card, CardActions, CardContent, CardMedia, IconButton, Typography, CardHeader, Avatar } from '@material-ui/core';
 import MoreVertIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';
 
 const Post = ({ post }) => {
    return (
        <Card>
            <CardMedia image={post.companyLogo} />
            <CardHeader
                avatar={
                <Avatar aria-label="recipe">
                    <img href={post.employerImage}/>
                </Avatar>
                }
                action={
                <IconButton aria-label="settings">
                    <MoreVertIcon />
                </IconButton>
                }
                title={post.employerName}
                subheader={post.jobTitle}
            />
            <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">{post.responsibility.map((tag) => `️${tag} `)}</Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">{post.employedDate}</Typography>
            </CardActions>
        </Card>
    );
}

export default Post;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, please log the post object inside Post the component and check that is post object is accessible inside the Post component or not, first ensure that the parent component is passing data properly to the child Post component or not. 

After this, Check out the Card example on Material UI. I can see that you haven't given any width to Card. try to give Card width manually and check it. also give some height, width to the media to check it properly.  you can refer Card component here. [Material UI Card](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/) 

Check these 2 things first.

Comment: You should install the React Developer Tools browser extension so that you can look that the tree of rendered components.  That will help you see if the list of `Post` components are there but invisible or if they are not there at all.

Comment: @AksharSarvaiya Yes I was able to console log the post object inside my post component.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting response from the db, there must be a rendering error.
From a quick look I see that you have missused the `Avatar` component.

It should be like: `<Avatar alt="recipe" src={post.employerImage} />`

or if you want to utilize the `children` prop, img tag takes `src` not `href`:

```
<Avatar aria-label="recipe">
    <img src={post.employerImage}/>
</Avatar>
```